# Centering Picture In MFMailComposeViewController (iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, image, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, centering

Is it possible to center an image when attaching it to the MFMailComposeViewController in XCode? Here's the code I'm using:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"millersicon" ofType:@"png"];
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
[picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"millersicon"];
```

It places the image in the e-mail when the Mail Application comes up but it's left aligned. Is there a way to center it? I couldn't find any information on it. Thanks.